# Adding select options to a combobox with crossrider

Tags: jquery, html, crossrider

I'm writing an extension using Crossrider. I'm displaying an HTML form that contains a combobox and am trying to add selection options to it. (Outside crossrider the code is working.)

```
for (var i=0;i<country_list.length;i++)
{
    country_txt = '<option value='+i+'>'+country_list[i]+'</option>';
    console.log(country_txt);
    $('#countrySelect').append(country_txt);
}
```

The code is displayed correctly on the console, but the append doesn't work. There are no errors in the error console.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I just created a crossrider extension with the same data, assuming `country_list=["Country1","Country2"]` and added it to a page with nothing but a `countrySelect` id'd div and it works. The problem is not with this code, try logging, putting a `debugger;` statement and other techniques

Comment: How are you calling the above code? All the syntax looks correct.

Comment: @user2157981 An extension can only interact with a page's DOM if the code is run in the [Extension Page](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes) scope. Can you confirm that this code is in your extension.js file or a file called by it? If you haven't already resolved the problem, as a Crossrider employee, I am happy to help you debug if you can provide me with the extension Id.

Comment: The code is in another js that I includede to the extension.js. The code is running, because it is writing to the console.
Shlomo, how can I contact you in private?

Comment: I'm getting a crossrider error:

Error: TypeError: a.eval is undefined
Source File: chrome://crossriderapp#####/content/crossriderapi.js
Line: 43

Comment: @Liat Rather than give out my email here, please either open a support ticket at http://support.crossrider.com or email support@crossrider.com with the details. Then I will contact you accordingly. Thanks